# PHP - Keep values in select dropdown after values are sent to another validation PHP file

Tags: php, html

I have an PHP (register.php) form that is verfied in another file (register-val.php). If there are an errors or incomplete data the user is sent back to register.php to amend the mistakes.

I have a mixture of both input and drop down menus. If there are an errors or incomplete data the user is sent back to register.php to amend the mistakes.

The form keeps the data transfered from register-val.php using $_SESSION. While this works for input, this does not completely work for dropdown menus. The dropdown menu selection works but I get an error in my error_log. This is a sample dropdown menu.

```
<select id="gender" name="gender" tabindex="auto"/>
<option <?php if(($_SESSION['gender']) == '') { echo 'selected="selected"';}  ?> value="">Select gender</option>
<option <?php if(($_SESSION['gender']) == 'Male') { echo 'selected="selected"';}  ?> value="Male">Male</option>
<option <?php if(($_SESSION['gender']) == 'Female') { echo 'selected="selected"';}  ?> value="Female">Female</option>
<option <?php if(($_SESSION['gender']) == 'Other') { echo 'selected="selected"';}  ?> value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

This is what I tried:

```
<?php if(!empty($_SESSION['gender'])){unset($_SESSION['gender']);} //To destroy session if there isn't any ?>
```

In the code

```
<select id="gender" name="gender" tabindex="auto"/>
<option <?php if(($_SESSION['gender']) == '') { echo 'selected="selected"';}  ?> value="">Select gender</option>
<option <?php if(($_SESSION['gender']) == 'Male') { echo 'selected="selected"';}  ?> value="Male">Male</option>
<option <?php if(($_SESSION['gender']) == 'Female') { echo 'selected="selected"';}  ?> value="Female">Female</option>
<option <?php if(($_SESSION['gender']) == 'Other') { echo 'selected="selected"';}  ?> value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

I get the following error in my error log when I refresh the page to enter the details from the begining, everytime I do not select an option.

**Undefined index: gender**

How can I go about it,please?

**SOLUTION** Thanks to  wookie919

```
if (array_key_exists('gender', $_SESSION)) {
    if ($_SESSION['gender'] == '') {
        $_SESSION[''] = 'Male';
    }
    elseif ($_SESSION['gender'] == 'Male') {
        $_SESSION['gender'] = 'Male';
    }
    elseif ($_SESSION['gender'] == 'Female') {
        $_SESSION['gender'] = 'Female';
    }
    elseif ($_SESSION['gender'] == 'Other') {
        $_SESSION['gender'] = 'Other';
    }
}
else {
    $_SESSION['gender'] = '';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access `$_SESSION['gender']` when `$_SESSION['gender']` does not exist.

Thus before trying to access `$_SESSION['gender']`, check that the index `'gender'` exists in `$_SESSION`:

```
if (array_key_exists('gender', $_SESSION)) {
    // $_SESSION['gender'] exists
    if ($_SESSION['gender'] == 'Male') {
    }
    // etc, etc,
}
else {
    // $_SESSION['gender'] does not exist, so don't try to access it.
}
```

Comment: @user2333968 Sorry, but I don't understand exactly what you don't understand regarding the else statement. $_SESSION['gender'] only starts to exist once you initialize it, probably by assigning a value to it e.g. $_SESSION['gender'] = 'Male'; So if $_SESSION['gender'] does not exist, what does it mean for you? This is something that you must consider and handle appropriately. For example, should 'Select gender' be selected when $_SESSION['gender'] does not exist?